# create diagonal separated div with vertical and horizontal overflow hidden text

Tags: html, css

I have a question for all CSS masters out there. I want to create a single div with a background image. The div is separated with a diagonal line and the text content is shown in a way like in the photo below.

I already built the backend for this little project. The goal was to create a backend that provides random sentences out of a novel after the user selects two pages - then the "digital dogear" is created. Sadly I'm not very skilled at CSS so I struggle with more advanced CSS. I hope someone here can lend me his knowledge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's several processes required here: 1), create the two diagonal pieces separately before you fit them in place 2) figure out how you're going to do the diagonal covers - most likely with a triangle shape + an overflow of the text. 3) rotate and fit em in place accordingly. My suggestion would be to have a look at  https://9elements.com/blog/pure-css-diagonal-layouts/ and https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-triangles-using-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy idea using one element:

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: justify;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  background: gold;
  color: #fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 40px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background: inherit;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -2px;
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc euismod pharetra mi id auctor. Ut sagittis tortor venenatis fermentum auctor. Curabitur dictum tristique tincidunt. ">
Phasellus rutrum odio a magna auctor facilisis. Mauris vehicula tortor non nibh volutpat, non aliquam libero convallis. Quisque dignissim feugiat efficitur.
</div>
```